# Pass a condition occurring within a foreach loop as a parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method for adding data from some student objects in a list to a datatable. The method checks for students in the studentList that meet a certain condition and then adds them to the datatable.

I want to specify the condition in the parameter, however I (understandably) get an error when I try to pass in **s.status** as my second string parameter, since **s** doesn't come into play until the foreach loop starts. Is there a way to make this work?

```
    public void AddDataTableRows(DataTable datatable, string field, string condition)
    {
       foreach (student s in studentList)
       {
           if (field == condition)
           {
               datatable.Rows.Add(s.name, 
                   s.totalDays, 
                   s.improveOverall,
                   s.totalClassDays,
                   s.instructor,
                   s.grade);
           }

       }
   }
```

The call that I want to make

```
AddDataTableRows(DataTable1, s.status, "active");
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Predicate` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be something like this

```
public void AddDataTableRows(DataTable datatable, Func<Student,bool> cond)
{
    foreach (student s in studentList)
    {
        if (cond(s))
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(s.name,
                s.totalDays,
                s.improveOverall,
                s.totalClassDays,
                s.instructor,
                s.grade);
        }

    }
}
```

You can call it now as `AddDataTableRows(...., s => s.Status == "active");`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes but since `theB` answered that way, I didn't want to edit my answer.

Comment: @Eser upvote and add link from your answer is quite acceptable solution in this case like : "...or you can use `studentList.Where(cond)` as shown in  [theB answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32363938/477420)".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I upvoted it. But incorporating his answer to this makes me feel like *stealing* his future upvotes. I'll skip that part.

Comment: @Eser - If you want to add that to your answer feel free.  I'll happily delete mine.  If you do, please also consider including a note about the `Predicate<T>` type.  Just @ tag me with whatever you decide.  I'm not here to rep farm :-)

Comment: @Eser Opinion: I don't think *linking* (vs. copy-paste) to other answer from accepted one will be stealing votes - I'd expect other way: people only look at accepted one, and maybe linked. That issues is frequently discussed on META in slightly different context of "how to deal with outdated accepted/highly voted questions". Also "how to properly incorporate other answers" may be good question for META (probably already discussed - check first  if you decide to ask one).

Answer (score 3):

You could make the argument a `Predicate<Student>`.  This makes the function:

```
public void AddDataTableRows(DataTable datatable, Predicate<Student> condition)
{
    foreach (student s in studentList.Where(condition))
    {
        datatable.Rows.Add(s.name,
                           s.totalDays,
                           s.improveOverall,
                           s.totalClassDays,
                           s.instructor,
                           s.grade);
    }
}
```

Which you would then call like this:

```
AddDataTableRows(table, (s) => s.status == "active");
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is this:

```
public void AddDataTableRows(DataTable datatable, Func<student, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (student s in studentList)
    {
        if (predicate(s))
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(s.name,
                s.totalDays,
                s.improveOverall,
                s.totalClassDays,
                s.instructor,
                s.grade);
        }

    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
AddDataTableRows(datatable, s => s.Status == "enrolled");
```